# VB.NET - How to make textbox accept only one character per keypress?

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, richtextbox

My project is to simulate the Enigma Machine and I need some help dealing with the visual interface.

In my program I need to have a textbox in which the user can enter an unlimited number of letters. However, the program also updates other components based on the text entered, and displays a visual representation for the user.

For example, when I press the letter 'A' the program encodes it to say, the letter 'S' and displays an image into the interface. However, that encoding is unique every time the letter is encoded.

As you know, when you keep a letter pressed on the keyboard for a longer time, it keeps writing that letter. For example, if I keep 'A' pressed, in my textbox I end up with 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', and it spams the image display as it encodes every single 'A'.

My question is: How can I limit the textbox to accept only one letter per keypress, but still allowing double or triple letter? So I can have a substring of identical characters, as long as I input them by pressing repeatedly on the keyboard.

I need this so the encoded leter lights up for as long as the input letter is being pressed.

Comment: Does it need to support or remove support for control characters (e.g. arrow keys, backspace, delete)?

Comment: It needs to support them

Comment: For most situations, the simple `KeyUp` handlers, as demonstrated in the answers below, are sufficient.  However, technically, the `KeyUp` event isn't guaranteed to fire in all cases.  For instance, if another window receives focus while the key was being held down, the `KeyUp` event would not fire.  In that case, the next legitimate key press would end up getting ignored.  If that's a concern, take a look at [this other Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420981/stopping-keys-from-repeating-c) which has a more thorough solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the SuppressKeyPress within the KeyEventArgs, you can control when a keypress is completed.  In my example I use a textbox as the control being typed into.  But this will work with other controls as well...

```
Dim keyIsDown As Boolean 'marked to give status of keyboard key

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If keyIsDown Then 'if key is already down abort
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    keyIsDown = True 'if key was not already down mark it as down now   
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    keyIsDown = False 'key has traveled up clear the marker
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I just want to add for other who might want to use your code to add the following line before the `If keyIsDown Then` line in the `TextBox1_KeyDown` sub. This will make it so that you can still long press the arrow keys and backspace for text index selection and deletion.

`If e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then Exit Sub`

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not it is a repeated key is not something you can find out in the key events.  But it is available in the underlying [WM_KEYDOWN message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), bit #30 of the lparam argument will be set to 1.  By far the easiest way to take a peek at that message is by overriding the form's ProcessCmdKey() method.  Paste this code into your form class:

```
Private repeatedKey As Boolean

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    repeatedKey = (msg.LParam.ToInt32 And (1 << 30)) <> 0
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

You can now check this variable in your KeyPressed event handler.  I'd imagine you want to do something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If repeatedKey Then e.Handled = True
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(22) Then e.Handled = True '' Disable paste
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(8) Then e.Handled = False '' Allow repeating backspace
End Sub
```

The 1st line prevents repeated keys from being seen at all.  The 2nd line disables copy/pasting, unlikely to be useful in your app.  The 3rd line still allows repeating the backspace key so the user can easily correct a mistake.  Keep in mind that I'm just guessing what you want to do here, it is just an example and you probably want to change it.

Comment: Great info, but I think you mean `(msg.LParam.ToInt32 And (1 << 30)) <> 0` rather than that VB# hybrid....

Comment: Thanks, I wrote and tested this in C# first.  Oops.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a boolean flag to determine whether a first `keypress` event fired, then cancel any next `keypress` until the `KeyUp` event fires.

```
Private isKeyHandled As Boolean = False

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) _
Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    e.Handled = Me.isKeyHandled 
    Me.isKeyHandled = True

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) _
Handles TextBox1.KeyUp

    Me.isKeyHandled = False

End Sub
```

Also, to accommodate you could add the logic into a sub-classed TextBox:

```
Public Class TextBoxEx : Inherits TextBox

    Public Property DisableKeyRepetition As Boolean = False

    Private isKeyHandled As Boolean = False

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)

        MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)

        If Me.DisableKeyRepetition Then
            e.Handled = Me.isKeyHandled
            Me.isKeyHandled = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyUp(ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)

        MyBase.OnKeyUp(e)
        Me.isKeyHandled = False

    End Sub

End Class
```

Then:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.TextBoxEx1.DisableKeyRepetition = True

End Sub
```